# Animated dice framework for XNA?

Tags: xna, animation

I'm looking for a reusable 3d animated dice component I can reuse in my XNA board game.

I know it might be wishful thinking in hoping such a component exists, but at the same time worthwhile checking.

I'm looking for something that can give a realistic dice animation and return the dice result that matches the animation.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Oh that was also something I was looking for a while.

Comment: I'll check out that silverlight dice, looks pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

There is one that exists for Silverlight [here](http://www.edwardsmale.co.uk/Dice). It'll likely be fairly simple to convert that to full XNA. The source code is available and from what I can tell the creator's intention is to have it easily "plug-able" into existing projects.